# Number of principal components for PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering, feature-weighting

Which criteria to consider while picking the number of principal components for PCA?

Comment: The number of PCs is not something to be chosen; it is entirely determined by the number of variables (and number of observations, if it's less than or equal to the number of variables). Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your problem. If the PCA is part of preprocessing for regression / machine learning, then you should treat the number of PCA components as a hyper parameter and pick the number that optimizes the cross validated score.
If you are not using it in a regression pipeline, then you often select the number of components where the sum of the explained variance sum to 75% / 90 % or similar values that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a number of components that enable you to capture a good amount of variance.

Say, for example, 85% variance is being explained by 10 Principal components , so keep 10.

This technique is useful for low dimensions.

However , it is questionable whether high variance = high importance. Especially in high dimensions .

Another approach is , you could treat the number of components as a hyperparameter and tune it using cross validation.